# $\forall n \exists c(n) \in (0, 1)$ such that: $\frac{1}{n}\int\limits_0^1 f(x) dx=\int\limits_0^{2c(n)} f(x) dx+\int\limits_{1-3c(n)}^1 f(x) dx $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, proof-writing

Let $f: [0, 1] \to [0, +∞)$ be a continuous function. Show that for every $n$ there exists $c(n) \in (0, 1)$ such that:

$$\frac{1}{n}\int\limits_0^1 f(x) dx=\int\limits_0^{2c(n)} f(x) dx+\int\limits_{1-3c(n)}^1 f(x) dx$$

Now, I know that it looks like something that could be proven with mean value theorem for integrals. However, on the RHS we have 2 separate integrals, so we would be working on 2 different $c(n)$ values and that is problematic. There is probably some way to merge those integrals.

However I don't know how to do that since their scopes move in other directions when $c(n)$ changes.

- The scope of $\int\limits_0^{2c(n)} f(x) dx$ gets bigger when $c(n)$ gets bigger
- The scope of $\int\limits_{1-3c(n)}^1 f(x) dx$ gets smaller

They can cross each other or not even reach each other. I don't know what to do - any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: Choosing $c=0$ and $c=1/5$, then the values of $RHS-LHS$ in two cases have opposite sign. From which you can apply Intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

$2x=1-3x\implies x=\frac 15$.

Assuming that $ f $ is not the zero function.

For $ n>1$ and $ x\in[0,\frac 15] $,  put

$$F(x)=\frac 1n\int_0^1f-\int_0^{2x}f-\int_{1-3x}^1f$$

$ F $ is continuous at $ [0,\frac 15] $ because
$$\forall x\in[0,\frac 15]\; [0,2x]\subset[0,1]\; and\; [1-3x,1]\subset[0,1]$$

$$F(0)=\frac 1n\int_0^1f\color{red}{>0}$$

$$F(\frac 15)=\frac 1n\int_0^1f-\int_0^1f$$
$$=(\frac 1n-1)\int_0^1f\color{red}{<0}$$
By IVT,

$$\exists c_n\in(0,\frac 15)\;\;:\;\; F(c_n)=0$$
done!

Comment: Thank you, I tried to replicate your way of thinking (IVT) for n < 1 but it seams impossible cause for n close to 0 the first integral can be arbitrarily big. Therefore I can not think of any interval of x to make the function change sign.

Comment: @mathbb It is a good and new kind of question.

Comment: So it can't be done using IVT? Is it even possible at all (for $n < 1$)?

Comment: @mathbb You mean, it is still true for $ n<0$.

Comment: No, I know that the idea presented above (in your answer) works only for $n>1$, but I need to prove that for every $n$. So I need to think about $n<1$ now. Therefore I asked if you know if it could be done using $IVT$ also.

Comment: @mathbb If $ n<0 $ , then the LHS is negative while the RHS is positive.

Comment: Right, so the equality doesn't work for $n < 0$ (there is no $c(n)$ such that equality holds),

Comment: @mathbb Yes, that is what you can conclude.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, I am just surprised because it means that there is an error in my textbook. Maybe they forgot to mention that $n>1$ or $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Because for $n \in (0;1)$ it seems to not make sense either.

Comment: @mathbb The notation $ n $, in general, means that $ n\in \Bbb N$, if not one will precise it.

Comment: You are probably right, I didn't see a sequence for long enough to not think of any $n$ in terms of naturals. Never mind, thank you for your help - the idea of $n \in mathbb{R}$ would hold me back for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $n$. The r.h.s is a continuous function of $c(n)$.  For $c(n)=0$, r.h.s. $=0$.  For $c(n)\ge 1/2$, r.h.s. $\ge n\times$ l.h.s., since $f(x)\ge 0$.  Continuity implies there is a $c(n)$ where there is equality.